# How to Change Background When You Pass a Certain Point on Page using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a sidebar and the various sections on a page. The sidebar floats left and the sections float right. I would like the sidebar color/background to change when it passes each section, so when it is on the first section it is red, second section blue and third section green. I have attached an example with the HTML/CSS. If someone could help me fill in the jQuery, that would be awesome.

http://jsfiddle.net/fkYZp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/fkYZp/9/

Could definitely be prettied up to use a class etc. But here is the basic concept.

```
     var lifeStylePos = $('#lifestyle-sidebar').offset().top - y,
         onePos = $("#one").offset().top - y,
         twoPos = $("#two").offset().top - y,
         threePos = $("#three").offset().top - y;

     if(lifeStylePos  > threePos){
         $('#lifestyle-sidebar').css({'background' : 'green'});
     }else if(lifeStylePos > twoPos){
          $('#lifestyle-sidebar').css({'background' : 'blue'});
     }else if(lifeStylePos  > onePos){
          $('#lifestyle-sidebar').css({'background' : 'red'});
     }
```

Comment: This is almost it, but when I run it, it seems to change to blue when the bottom of the sidebar gets to top of section 2, and then to green when the top of the sidebar gets to the top of section 2 (instead of when the bottom of the sidebar gets to the top of section 3). How would you correct this? See here where I've added breaks between the paragraphs. [http://jsfiddle.net/fkYZp/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/fkYZp/5/)

Comment: If I understand you want it to update when the top of the sidebar is in line with the content. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Added -y to var lifeStylePos = $('#lifestyle-sidebar').offset().top

Answer (score 2):

You might give the [jQuery Waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) a try.

Comment: This would work. If I can do it with only 8-10 lines of code, I would prefer to that and not have to install a plugin though. If the above answer doesn't work though Waypoints would work. Thanks for the help!